# Cookie Problem - Magento does not remember the user

Tags: login, cookie

there are tons of articles about this subject, but it seems that none of them work for me.

I have two magento installations on my server:

```
domain.com
domain.com/test
```

On both installations I have the following settings:
[image]

I set "only use http" to "no", but still the issue exists. I tried to enter "domain.com/test" in the cookie domain section, but after I did this I was not able to login anymore.

In the database I have the following settings:

```
web/unsecure/base_url -> https://domain.com/test/
web/secure/base_url -> https://domain.com/test/
```

Does anybody know why the system will not remember the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

domain.com/test isn't a cookie domain domain.com can be one.
Try setting the cookie domain to .domain.com
But you might have issues as the cookies will be accessible for both magento sites, it would be much simpler to have two actual domain names and then set each site's cookie domain correctly.

Comment: Do I enter test.domain.com without https:// in the cookie domain field?

Comment: The cookie domain is just the domain so does not include the https://

It would only be test.domain.com if you accessed your second site on this address, you said above you accessed it via domain.com/test so that would make the cookie domain 
.domain.com